# replace onpage text with jquery and prompt file download

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Alright so here is what I am trying to do.

Ones user uses short link ?f=xHnAnn they are then send to /psn/xHnAnn.aspx where they get a Thank You message and the file is pushed to the browser.

What I want to do with jQuery is when user are send to that page they see Preparing text and when 2200 ms delay passes and file is pushed to user the Preparing is changed into Thank You.

I don't currently use or have any jQuery written up. I am using basic JavaScript for the delayed push.

```
<?php if($_GET['f'] == 'xHnAnn') { ?> //just an example actuall code has == $itemID

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function delay(){
    window.location = "psn/xHnAnn.aspx?hash=fa456f8df65663d9fb"
}
//-->
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Raminson anything wrong with that?

Comment: I think seconds is a little bit long time, no user wants to wait so long... I think you mean milliseconds ;-) e.g. 2.2 seconds

Comment: @yckart i had to use 2200 as for some reason mt_rand(1,10) in PHP does not want to generate value fast enough to be pushed into inline CSS for different background, forcing the background image not to be displayed but instead only the background-color. I would not want any one wait more then few seconds 2-3 but mt_rand does not want to work :(

Comment: @Cl' Other than being a little bit short of 37 minutes, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it (using jQuery):

```
​<p id="status">Preparing text...</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $("#status").html(​​​​​​​​​"Thanks for waiting!");
    }, 2200);
</script>​​​​​​​​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/f3vUg/1/)

If you want to change the delay between the text change from 2200 ms to 2200 seconds (37 mins to load??), then replace the `2200` in the above code with `2200000`.

Or if you'd prefer not to use jQuery, you could use pure javascript instead:

```
​<p id="status">Preparing text...</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = ​​​​​​​​​"Thanks for waiting!";
    }, 2200);
</script>​​​​​​​​​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/f3vUg/2/)

Comment: Ops, i did not realize I put in sec instead of ms. Not its 2200 ms. What an idiot I am, but i am not wearing my glasses at the moment so my sight a'int the best :(

Answer (score 1):

I've written something for you:

```
function delay(time) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("thanks").innerHTML = "Thank You!";
    }, time);
}
delay(2200);
```

​

And a **[short Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVTSX/)**

Comment: I get where you are going with this, but in my case PHP writes values directly into inline CSS. And the background is no separate div background its in actual body :D                              body { 
     background-image: url("/assets/<?php echo mt_rand(1,4); ?>.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font: 11px/150% Arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  }